# How to get touched location in AndEngine?

Tags: andengine

I'm new in AndEngine and there is too many hard things for me now..
 I want to know where I touched when I touch anywhere, and give actions by those locations with x and y. Can anybody help me?

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried it with onclicklistener, which i saw on here http://youtu.be/Q0kjiIH6u-M.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go throught the AndEngine Examples. There are two methods. Either you register touch on an Entity, as shown for example in TouchAndDrag example:

```
    final Sprite sprite = new Sprite(centerX, centerY, this.mFaceTextureRegion, this.getVertexBufferObjectManager()) {
        @Override
        public boolean onAreaTouched(final TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent, final float pTouchAreaLocalX, final float pTouchAreaLocalY) {
            this.setPosition(pSceneTouchEvent.getX() - this.getWidth() / 2, pSceneTouchEvent.getY() - this.getHeight() / 2);
            return true;
        }
    };
```

Or you use the touch listener on a Scene. You have to implement the IOnSceneTouchListener and then set it in your scene:

```
public class MyListener implements IOnSceneTouchListener  {

    @Override
    public boolean onSceneTouchEvent(Scene pScene, final TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent) {
        if (pSceneTouchEvent.isActionDown()) {
                //execute action.
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}

...

scene.setOnSceneTouchListener(new MyListener ());
```

You can find most of the code needed in the examples already. [See this tutorial](http://android.kul.is/2013/09/tutorial-andengine-extensions-and-examples.html) on how to add them to Eclipse.